# Use currently authorized user in resource attribute during create request

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest

I have entity which does have `MyUser author;` attribute. I use also this class in custom authorization process to create `MyUserPrincipal` instance. (I have taken inspiration from Callicoder [blog post](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/) and [repository](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/).)

Snippet of logging procedure part:

```java
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {
    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        // He I use myUserRepository, to load MyUser instance and than return MyUserPrincipal which implements OAuth2User, UserDetails...
    }
}
```

Now I have repository for Book entity for example. Book can look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Getters // project lombook magic here
@Setters
public class Book {
    private MyUser author;
    private String title;
}
```

I can create new resource using POST request to http://localhost/api/books with data like this:

```
{
 "author":"api/authors/42",
 "title":"stackoverflow forever"
}
```

**My question**: Is it possible to easily (without custom controller) make use of "authentication.principal.userId" from `SecurityContext` to fill in author ow newly created resource/entiry? I would like to forbid for user of my API to send author field at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what you mean by "custom controller", but the @RestController behind your `/api/books` URI can make use of `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. Then you don't have to send in your author id anymore, if it is part of `MyUserPrincipal`.

```
@PostMapping("/api/books")
public SomeDTO saveBook(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserPrincipal principal) {

  if (principal != null) { // user is logged in and not e.g. anonymous
     // principal.getId(); use this to save your book
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok, this seems readable (easy) enough, despite "own controller" from my point of view. I will try to go this way.